# Filter based off of nested object

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out the best way to filter the nested object to get every category with an id of '2' or whatever. Want it so it only return those specific nodes.

```
const data = [
  {
    node: {
      categories: [
        {id: 2 }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [
        {id: 3}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [
        {id: 3}
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [
        { id: 5 } 
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [
        { id: 2 }
      ]
    }
  },
]
```

Tried something like this but doesn't seem to work.

```
return data.filter(e => {
  return e.node.categories.forEach(category => {
        category.id == '2';
      });
    });
```

Comment: Can there be multiple categories?

Comment: Yeah each node can have multiple categories

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return any node which has a category id of 2, you can filter based on [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the `id` values being equal to `2`:

```js
const data = [
  {
    node: { categories: [ { id: 2 } ] }
  },
  {
    node: { categories: [ { id: 3 } ] }
  },
  {
    node: { categories: [ { id: 3 } ] }
  },
  {
    node: { categories: [ { id: 5 } ] }
  },
  {
    node: { categories: [ { id: 2 } ] }
  },
]

const result = data.filter(e => e.node.categories.some(c => c.id == 2));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

we can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search if the `category` contain specific `id` or not.

```js
const data = [
  {
    node: {
      categories: [{ id: 2 }],
    },
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [{ id: 3 }],
    },
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [{ id: 3 }],
    },
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [{ id: 5 }],
    },
  },
  {
    node: {
      categories: [{ id: 2 }],
    },
  },
];

const result = data.filter(({ node }) => {
  return node.categories.find((cat) => cat.id === 2);
});

console.log(result);
```